# value of "this" in javascript constructor function when called with new and as a regular function

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am not able to understand the following code,

```
function Foo(arg) { 

  if (!(this instanceof Foo)){
      alert("inside if statement");
      return new Foo(arg);
  }

  else{
    alert("inside else statement")
  }

  this.myArg = arg;

}

let foo_obj = Foo("bar");
alert(foo_obj.myArg);
```

When the program is executed, when if statement is first encountered, it checks whether *"this"* (which is the window object then) has *"Foo"* in its prototype chain, since it is not there the following is executed

> return new Foo(arg);

So Foo is called again, but this time the *"else"* part is executed. Why is that so? What is the value of *"this"* the second time?

Comment: The `new` operator initializes a new object and calls the constructor with `this` a reference to it.

Comment: In JavaScript a class constructor is a function (well it's a function in all languages) so you can in practice call the function directly (you usually can't in other languages) instead of using it to construct a class. That if / else there just differentiates between the function being used as a constructor (with `new`) or being called as a function (without `new`).

Comment: It's just to make it so that `var obj = Foo("bar")` does the same as `var obj = new Foo("bar")`, IOW: it's just to make sure a new instance of Foo is created,.

Comment: @Pointy So "this" refers to the object initialized in the constructor function when called with "new"?

Comment: Yes, if called with `new`, `this` will equal an instance of `Foo`, but if it's not called with `new` it will be undefined, or window if not in strict mode.  Personally I don't like this instancing shorthand, if you want a new instance of an object, is more specific for it to have `new Class()`,.  if you want to force the constructor to use `new`, I would personally throw an exception instead.

Comment: @Keith Thank you, for the clarification.